# Floating point number needs to be displayed as a fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

Request you to suggest regarding the below problem.

First we have to divide a numerator by the denominator in order to obtain a floating point number.
Then the digits after the decimal needs to be displayed as a fraction.

When 9 is divided by 4 it has to be displayed as 2 1/4.This is working fine.

When 13 is divided by 5 it needs to be displayed as 2 3/5.

**My code is not working for the second case.** Getting output as

```
2 5404319552844595/9007199254740992.
```

STEP1:
Divided the numerator by the denominator to find the quotient
Calculated the remainder using (`nmr%dnr`).

STEP 2:
Divided the remainder obtained the in above step by the denominator again.
Converted the floating point number into fractions by using the `Fractions` built in method.

STEP 3:
The output is stored in a tuple and the output is printed.
`t1=(int(q),r)`.

Code:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def printValue(num,den):
    rem=0.0;q=0.0;

    q=float(num)/float(den)
    rem=float(num)%float(den)

    if rem>0:
        #print ("%0.2f"%(rem/den))
        r=Fraction(round(rem/den,2))
        t1=(int(q),r)                    #Output is stored in a tuple
        return t1
    else:
        t2=(int(q),)
        return t2


num=int(input())
den=int(input())
z=printValue(num,den)
for i in z:
    print(i,end=" ")
```

Comment: `9/4` can be represented precisely by a `float`. `13/5` can not. try keeping `num` and `den` as integers and to the calculations form there...

Comment: *First we have to divide a numerator by the denominator in order to obtain a floating point number*. Are you really sure of that requirement??? IMHO passing by a **floating point** number just makes the operation more complex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [floating point is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3545273)... or more exactly it has a limited accuracy. A fractional number can only be exactly represented if its denominator is a power of 2, which explains that 9/4 gives the exact and expected result.

But Python is great. The `Fraction` class has a `limit_denominator()` method which helps in finding a *reasonable* fractional approximation of a floating point by searching a limited denominator (by default 1000000).

Demo:

```
>>> f = 3/5
>>> Fraction(f)
Fraction(5404319552844595, 9007199254740992)
>>> Fraction(f).limit_denominator()
Fraction(3, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My code got validated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `divmod`.

```
def printValue(num, den):
    x, r = divmod(num, den)
    print(f'{x if x else ""} {r}/{den}')

printValue(9, 4)
# prints:
2 1/4

printValue(13, 5)
# prints:
2 3/5

printValue(2, 5)
# prints:
 2/5
```